# How to access data across M2M tables in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the 'best practice' way of accessing data across a 1 (or more) many-to-many tables?
This is incredibly difficult for me as I am not sure what I shuld be googling/looking up.

I have attached a diagram of my data model. I am able to query data for 'C' related ot a user, by utilizing serializers.
there has to be a simpler way of doing this (I'm hoping).

Doing it with serializers seems incredibly limiting. I'd like to access a user's 'B' and 'C' and transform the object to only have a custom structure and possible unique values.

Any direction is much appreciated. Pretty new to Django, so I apologize for this newb type of question.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Django models. Normally it is better to think in terms of *models*, not tables. The idea is that Django will convert it to an SQL query that works with tables, but that is not what the programmer needs to be (much) concerned about.

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion. yeah these are what my models look like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of M2M relation using Django:

```py
class User(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(...)
 

class Song(models.Model)

    title = models.CharField(...)
    users_that_like_me = models.ManyToManyField('User', ..., related_name='songs_that_i_like')
```

So a `User` can like many `Song`s and a `Song` can be liked by many `User`s.

To see all the songs a user liked, we can do:

```py
user = User.objects.get(id='<the-user-id>')
liked_songs = user.songs_that_i_like.all()
```

And to see all the users who like a particular song we can similarly do:

```py
song = Song.objects.get(id='<the-song-id>')
users_that_like_this_song = song.users_that_like_me.all()
```

Both `liked_songs` and `users_that_like_this_song` are actually `querysets`, meaning we can do some Django magic on them.

For example, to find all users named Jon that liked this song we can do:

```py
users_that_like_this_song.filter(name='Jon')
```

We can also add some `property` shortcuts to our `Model`s to help with some common tasks, for example:

```py
class User(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def number_of_liked_songs(self): 
        return self.songs_that_i_like.count()
```

Then we can do:

```
user = User.objects.get(id='<the-user-id>')
number_of_songs_i_like = user.number_of_liked_songs
```

There's much more we can do with Django - if you're looking for something specific let us know.